# Empty SRC folder after import from github

Tags: java, eclipse, github, import, src

I'm currently working on a groupproject. We're using github to save our code. I have just installed eclipse to work on. I foound to open the project to use import. This has opened the project, except the SRC folder is empty whereas the first SRC folder (the main which was made through github) has several .java files within.
Why is this and how do I go about putting them in. I am unable to work on the code through eclipse at the moment due to this. Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to:

- clone manually the GitHub repo (in command line)
- import the Eclipse project in your Eclipse workpace
- Then [push to the GitHub repo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/File:Egit-0.10-github-pushurl.png]

Or you can clone the [GitHub project through Egit directly](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#clone_respository),,  following [this tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial).

---

The [OP pokeairguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3344370/pokeairguy) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560769/empty-src-folder-after-import-from-github/22575175#comment34376007_22575175) an alternative solution:

> - create a new project in eclipse like normal.
> - Then drag the contents of the `src` folder from GitHub into the folder directory within eclipse.
> - Then selecting link in the pop up window.
>
> I think it works by thinking its a new project but saves everyone done under the GitHub folder, for GitHub to work.

Comment: Thanks, I asked someone in my team and he said an alternate way which has worked. Thanks anyway, much appreciated

Comment: @pokeairguy sure. What was that alternate way?

Comment: It was create a new project in eclipse like normal. Then drag the contents of the src folder from github into the folder directory within eclipse. Then selecting link in the pop up window. I think it works by thinking its a new project but saves everyone done under the github folder, for github to work. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @pokeairguy Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer, for more visibility, and for others to use.